# Java - Displaying a title within a contentPane Container

Tags: java, swing

I am a newbee so advise and help is always greatly appreciated.

Cannot seem to get my container contentPane to display the title.

My code:

```
class CreateStockCodeDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

     OptraderSA parent;


     OptraderGlobalParameters GV = new OptraderGlobalParameters();
     private boolean DEBUG = true; //Set DEBUG = true for Debugging

JButton SAVE_BUTTON     = new JButton("SAVE");
JButton CANCEL_BUTTON   = new JButton("CANCEL");

Font MyFont         = new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,24);

JLabel PriceBidLabel           = new JLabel("  Bid Price",JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel PriceAskLabel           = new JLabel("  Ask Price",JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel PriceMidLabel           = new JLabel("  Mid Price",JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel DividendLabel           = new JLabel("  Dividend",JLabel.LEFT);

JTextField PriceBid    = new JTextField(5);
JTextField PriceAsk    = new JTextField(5);
JTextField PriceMid    = new JTextField(5);
JTextField Dividend           = new JTextField(5);

JTextField NewUnderlyingCode  = new JTextField(10);

String NewCode;

 public void CreateStockDetails(String StockCode)
 {
       super("Hallo All");

       Container contentPane = getContentPane();
       setSize(400,500);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

       //Centre Screen To Right Of Main
  Dimension sd=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  super.setLocation(sd.width/2-100/2, sd.height/2-300/2);
```

Thanks

Kind Regards
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `JFrame`, `Window`, `JInternalFrame`, ect, just call

```
setTitle("Hallo");
```

Also, the call to super must be the first call in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the title to the JFrame and not the ContentPane

Answer (score 0):

A container doesn't have a setTitle() method. Please read the API.

In addition to setting the title of the JFrame, you can add a "titled" border around the content pane:

```
JPanel content = (JPanel)getContentPane();
content.setBorder( ... );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for an example of using a TitledBorder.

Comment: I do that in the other classes - thanks but am interested in why it is saying that my super is not first line which it is.

Comment: You are using super again here: super.setLocation(sd.width/2-100/2, sd.height/2-300/2);